# trigger playpause in mediaelements.js

Tags: jquery, mediaelement.js

How do I trigger the playpause button in MediaElements.js from a click on a list item?  It plays, but it won't pause.

I have an unordered list below the player as follows:

***HTML***

```
<audio id="#MainPlayer"> 
    <source src="Random.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<ul>
    <li class="sel" AudioLnk="Audio1.mp3"> Audio 1 </li>
    <li class="sel" AudioLnk="Audio2.mp3"> Audio 2 </li>
    <li class="sel" AudioLnk="Audio3.mp3"> Audio 3 </li>
</ul>
```

***JQuery***

```
$(".sel").click(function(){
    $("#MainPlayer").attr({
        "src" : $(this).attr("AudioLnk")
    });
    $(".mejs-playpause-button").trigger('click');
});
```

Intended behavior:
Clicking a list item changes the source in the audio player **and either plays or pauses playback** depending on whether the player was playing at the time the item was clicked.

Actual behavior:
Clicking a list item changes the source in the audio player and begins playing. **However, clicking never pauses the player.**

Answer (score 1):

I ended up accessing the play() and pause() methods directly rather than trying to trigger the button (I'll leave it to someone else to explain why that wasn't working). Anyway, the following code works the way I wanted:  Clicking a list item plays that track, clicking it again pauses the track.

NB: I switched to links and suppressed them with .preventDefault();  This means the audio is still accessible when the script is not supported.

***HTML***

```
<audio style="align:right" id="MainPlayer" controls="controls">
    <source src="Random.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<ul id="RecPlaylist" style="list-style-type: none; list-style-position: inside; padding-left: 0px; text-decoration: none; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <li><a class="sel" href="Audio1.mp3">Audio 1</a>
    <li><a class="sel" href="Audio2.mp3">Audio 2</a>
    <li><a class="sel" href="Audio3.mp3">Audio 3</a>
</ul>
```

***JQuery***

```
$('audio').mediaelementplayer({ 
    success: function(media, domElement, player) {
        $('.sel').on('click', function( event ) {
            if ($(this).attr("href") != media.src) {
                media.setSrc($(this).attr("href"));
            }
            if (media.paused) {
                media.play();
            } else {
                media.pause();
            }
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    },
    audioHeight: 5,audioWidth: 200,features: ['progress','duration','tracks','playpause']
});
```